# UIApplicationShortcutIcon(templateImageName: "imagename from .xcassets") showing black blank image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, 3dtouch

I've tried .png image from .xcassets bundle of my project to create a UIApplicationShortcutIcon using init.templateImageName option as below.

```
icon = UIApplicationShortcutIcon(templateImageName: "john3")
let type = "com.company.app.sendChatTo"
let subtitle = "Send a chat"
let shortcutItem1 = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: type, localizedTitle: contactName, localizedSubtitle: subtitle, icon: icon, userInfo: nil)
let shortcutitems = [shortcutItem1]
UIApplication.shared.shortcutItems = shortcutitems
```

but it's showing black blank image.

[image]

Whereas, its also detecting bounds size of image that it's portrait or landscape. but it's black. Here is my image.

[image]

Let me know if I'm missing something, it's easy and it should be done easily, unfortunately it's creating trivial issue.

Answer (score 1):

A template image is treated differently from a normal image.

From the UIApplicationShortcutIcon [`init(templateImageName: String)` API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationshortcuticon/1623367-init):

> Icons should be square, single color, and 35x35 points, as shown in these template files and as described in Template Images in UIKit User Interface Catalog and in iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

From the [UIKit User Interface Catalog guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7):

> #### Template Images
>
> In iOS 7, you can choose to treat any of the images in your app as a template—or stencil—image. When you elect to treat an image as a template, the system ignores the image’s color information and creates an image stencil based on the alpha values in the image (parts of the image with an alpha value of less than 1.0 get treated as completely transparent). This stencil can then be recolored using tintColor to match the rest of your user interface.

Your options for application shortcut icons are:

> - An icon from a system-provided library of common types, as described in the `UIApplicationShortcutIconType` enumeration
> - An icon derived from a custom template image in your app’s bundle and preferably in an asset catalog
> - An icon representing a contact in the user's address book, which you access through the ContactsUI framework